# How to write to raw string with jackson 2

Tags: java, jackson2

I want to write an object to a raw json String. for  example i have one class

```
class Tiger{
    String name;
    int age;
}

Tiger tiger = new Tiger("red", 12);
```

Then i use ObjectMapper of jackson to write it to string

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(tiger);
```

The result is:

```
 "{"name":"red","age":12}"
```

But i want to write the object to raw json string like this:

```
"{\"name\":\"red\",\"age\":12}"
```

I know that we can create a function to transform the normal string to raw string by adding "\", but i wonder is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Nicely written question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the output as json again, which will get it escaped:

```
String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(
                      objectMapper.writeValueAsString(tiger));
//outputs: "{\"name\":\"red\",\"age\":12}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you find the solutions

```
String result ="";
        try {
            result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(tiger));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't refresh the page while writing the answer on that you just post the answer